# Is there a specification or documentation for 127localhost.com

Tags: macos, dns

I recently [discovered](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22127localhost.com%22) that attempting to resolve `127localhost.com` on (at least OSX Lion) resolves to 127.0.0.1, is there a specification or documentation for this available?

I ask because it appears that (at least on OSX Lion) this is only available when a network connection is active (note that the network connection does not have to provide Internet access).

**Update:**
This question is now somewhat irrelevant  because the `127localhost.com` domain appears to have expired, for reference `vcap.me` is an alternative.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: The resolution of sub-domains on localhost, without having to add an entry for each sub-domain to `/etc/hosts`. An alternative technique is listed [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/22419/set-dns-server-on-os-x-even-when-without-internet-connection), but using `127localhost.com` fulfills my requirements (with the exception that is appears to need an active network connection) without requiring additional configuration.

Comment: 127localhost.com obviously needs an active internet connection since its dns servers are hosted at OVH.

Comment: If you see the results for the [search](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22127localhost.com%22) I linked to in my question, you will see people are implying that it is an OSX specific feature; which would imply that it should be available offline. Unless it is not OSX specific and is just a normal DNS resolution (which as your answer demonstrates, it also is).

Comment: Excluding [mikepackdev.com/](http://mikepackdev.com/blog_posts/17-testing-subdomains-with-rspec-and-capybara), I weren't able to find anything about this particular domain being an OSX feature. IMO, it is a normal DNS resolution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is specific to OS X, it is solving to 127.0.0.1 from here too:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;127localhost.com.              IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
127localhost.com.       86373   IN      A       127.0.0.1
```

NS records:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
127localhost.com.       86400   IN      NS      dns16.ovh.net.
127localhost.com.       86400   IN      NS      ns16.ovh.net.
```

Also it looks like it is maintened by a private owner http://who.is/whois/127localhost.com/.

What kind of documentation are you looking for ? There is not much to say, it is only a domain name who resolves to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was too hung up on this being an OS X feature to consider that it was just a normal DNS looking. Thanks.
Incidentally  where did your pasted output come from?

Comment: I used `dig`, it is a small utiliy for doing dns queries. The exact command I used was `dig A 127localhost.com` which means: tell me what are A records of 127localhost.com.

Answer (score 1):

It works simply because *someone registered that name* !

You shouldn't rely on it - they could change the address it points to, for example to a site holding a browser exploit...